# How can I have a timer that will not stop the execution of the program, and call a callback function afterwards?

Tags: c, time

What I want to accomplish is wait a specified time after making a call, and once that time has passed a callback function is called. I found some answers already but apparently, they halt the entire application within that time, which is something I need to avoid. How can I do this?

This is an example of what I want:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void callback_fn() {
    puts("Time is over!");
}
int main(void) {
    some_timer_t timer = create_timer(500); // 500 ms
    when_timer_is_over(callback_fn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to manually halt it. If you don't do that, it should just keep going after the interrupt is handled.

Comment: The actual usage is about a Gtk library, which doesn't support multithreading officially.

Comment: `alarm` or `setitimer`?

Comment: @AggelosT If the library doesn't support multithreading, you can't safely make a call to any function that uses that library asychronously.  To be able to do that, not only would the library have to be thread-safe, it would also have to be reentrant and async-signal-safe, which are even tighter restrictions than just being thread-safe.

Comment: add your os as a tag pls

Comment: Im looking for a cross platform solution, not Unix-only or Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX operating systems have a timer API: timer_create()
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html

Windows has its own: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/timers